# Why everyone hates the undead?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, warfare, politics, fantasy-races

After death some might turn into undead by different means of magic. when  brough back to life as an undead gaining new sheer strength and magic powers is to be expected while things like sense of hunger and pain are lost but they can still starve to death or be killed, memories are retained.  [image]
Some people are genetically set to turn automatically into undead after death, but the rest of the population can only be brought back to life by magical events only.

Since all undead retain their memories, most of them have no dangerous intents (they don't eat people), actually it's  not rare to find undead who want to go back to their families.

But almost every single living person just wants to straight out eliminate all undeads from existence.

Why would people want to exterminate undeads and what do they have to gain from it?

Corpses stop decaying after being brought back to life.

Comment: Are they still decaying or the process is halted at the moment of resurrection?

Comment: There seems to be little difference between life and this not-quite-death. The undead eat, remember, care, etc. If they still pay taxes, too, then I wouldn't call it death at all.

Comment: ...because, they stink, literally

Comment: Theme song: Nobody Likes You When You're Dead, by Zombina and the Skeletones.

Comment: Would you want to sleep in a bed with an undead??

Comment: @Renan was surprised to see this is actually a real song!

Comment: @Aganju you know about rules 34 and 35, right?

Comment: If any one of the thousands of video games involving zombies are an indicator - people want to eliminate the undead because it's a way to get your psychopathic fix without anyone worrying about the result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Undead are harbingers of bad-luck, people who spend time around them seem to constantly contract mysterious diseases.

Undead are an affront to nature, the gods demand souls in the afterlife which is impossible if the Undead don't go.

Undead are really conservative, being essentially from the previous generation. This causes a large amount of political conflict between them and their more progressive descendants.

"Undead are taking our jobs!" how can living workers possibly compete when the undead can do what they do but with potentially decades more experience, no fatigue and possibly even magic powers. A lot of people here in britain hate immigrants who are simply harder working on average than the british, this is that times twenty or so.

Plain simple xenophobia, sadly it's been highly common throughout history to fear the other purely for irrational and subjective reasons this is likely to be a massive issue with people who are literally walking corpses.

Jealousy, if I thought someone had some secret to eternal life and wasn't sharing it with me, i'd get very annoyed. If they told me "You just weren't born right" I'd get even more annoyed.

All of the above. In real life prejudices are built up over many years of systematic change brought about for a variety of reasons. There is no "one reason" for example this can be seen for all the myraid reasons people give for homophobia "God doesn't like it" to "It's not natural" to "I've met a homosexual and they sullied my opinion of the entire group." to "Everyone else hates them, why can't I?"

Answer (score 5):

**Instinct**

There's a principle which animators and game-developers and some robotics people refer to as the Uncanny Valley.  Things which don't actually closely resemble people, and don't actually move much like people, are not disturbing to view.  And as an animation or robot gets closer to looking and moving like a person, it get more appealing and sympathetic.

But, when something gets very close to being human, but is not quite there, it becomes viscerally horrifying to many people.  Dolls can strike many people as creepy.  Waxy, jerky-motioned manikins (or zombies!) are the stuff of horror movies.

There's speculation as to why people tend to react this way, but it's a commonly observed tendency.